# pygame mixer save audio to disk?

Tags: python, audio, python-2.7, save, pygame

Using pygame mixer, I open an audio file and manipulate it. I can't find a way to save the "Sound object" to a local file on disk.

```
sound_file = "output.mp3"
  sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(sound_file)
```

Is there any way to do this? I have been researching pygame mixer docs but I couldn't find anything related to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is almost two years old, but in case people are still looking for an answer: You **can** save PyGame Sound instances by using the `wave` module (native Python).

```
# create a sound from NumPy array of file
snd = pygame.mixer.Sound(my_sound_source)

# open new wave file
sfile = wave.open('pure_tone.wav', 'w')

# set the parameters
sfile.setframerate(SAMPLINGFREQ)
sfile.setnchannels(NCHANNELS)
sfile.setsampwidth(2)

# write raw PyGame sound buffer to wave file
sfile.writeframesraw(snd.get_buffer().raw)

# close file
sfile.close()
```

More info and examples on GitHub: https://github.com/esdalmaijer/Save_PyGame_Sound.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried this, so I'm only guessing that it might work.  The `pygame.mixer.Sound` object has a function called `get_raw()` which returns an array of bytes in Python 3.x, and a string in Python 2.x.  I think you might be able to use that array of bytes to save your sound.

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound.get_raw

I expect it would look something like this:

```
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(sound_file)
... # your code that manipulates the sound
sound_raw = sound.get_raw()
file = open("editedsound.mp3", "w")
file.write(sound_raw)
file.close()
```

Comment: It probably doesn't dump data for an mp3 file format. It is possible that it will be a wav file.

Comment: This DOESN'T WORK. Here's an excerpt from an ipython test:
In [23]: sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('FishPolka.mid')

In [24]: sr = sound.get_raw()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

E:\Documents and Settings\Me\Desktop\<ipython console> in <module>()

AttributeError: 'Sound' object has no attribute 'get_raw'

In [25]: sound.g
sound.get_buffer       sound.get_length       sound.get_num_channels sound.get_volume

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT an asnwer. It is a comment because the comment i wrote above is unclear because i can't figure out how to make carriage returns work.

My comment is: The above solution DOES NOT WORK.

Here is an excerpt from a test in with ipython.

```
In [23]: sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('FishPolka.mid')

In [24]: sr = sound.get_raw()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

E:\Documents and Settings\Me\Desktop\<ipython console> in <module>()

AttributeError: 'Sound' object has no attribute 'get_raw'

In [25]: sound.g
sound.get_buffer       sound.get_length       sound.get_num_channels sound.get_volume
```

Comment: What version of Pygame are you using?  The documentation (which I specifically linked to) clearly states that it is new in Pygame 1.9.2.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Haz. That's good news. I was using In [1]: import pygame

In [2]: pygame.version.ver
Out[2]: '1.9.1release'