How To Get Loudness of Sound Object
I'm trying to make a program that take's the user's microphone input, and then measures the loudness of it. The code is a combination of This script and Pyloudnorm;
import pygame as pg
import time
import soundfile as sf
import pyloudnorm as pyln

from pygame._sdl2 import (
    get_audio_device_names,
    AudioDevice,
    AUDIO_F32,
    AUDIO_ALLOW_FORMAT_CHANGE,
)
from pygame._sdl2.mixer import set_post_mix


pg.mixer.pre_init(44100, 32, 2, 512)
pg.init()

# init_subsystem(INIT_AUDIO)
names = get_audio_device_names(True)
print(names)

sounds = []
sound_chunks = []


def callback(audiodevice, audiomemoryview):
    # print(type(audiomemoryview), len(audiomemoryview))
    # print(audiodevice)
    sound_chunks.append(bytes(audiomemoryview))


def postmix_callback(postmix, audiomemoryview):
    print(type(audiomemoryview), len(audiomemoryview))
    print(postmix)


set_post_mix(postmix_callback)

audio = AudioDevice(
    devicename=names[0],
    iscapture=True,
    frequency=44100,
    audioformat=AUDIO_F32,
    numchannels=2,
    chunksize=512,
    allowed_changes=AUDIO_ALLOW_FORMAT_CHANGE,
    callback=callback,
)
# start recording.
audio.pause(0)

time.sleep(2.5)


sound = pg.mixer.Sound(buffer=b"".join(sound_chunks))

data, rate = sound
meter = pyln.Meter(rate) #
loudness = meter.integrated_loudness(data)
print(loudness)

However this results in an error of "cannot unpack non-iterable Sound object" as the original version was designed to analyze audio files outright. Trying to analyze the raw chunks or the bytestring data via sound.get_raw() results in errors as well.
Is there any way to apply this analysis to the generated sound object, or if not, a way to convert the sound object to an audio file? To my knowledge Pygame does not allow you to save audio files. I would also prefer not to use Pyaudio, as I've been running into trouble with it.

How do you define "loudness"?  The raw data here is just going to be an array of 32-bit floating point values.  You can use array or struct to convert the byte string to an array of floats,  The range is -1.0 to 1.0, so you can figure out how close to 1.0 you get.

good question.

The sampling rate was defined during initialisation of pygaming and once again second time during initialisation of the mic AudioDevice class (see frequency attribute).
the input to the pyln.Meter should be an array, not the bytes sound object.

To sum up you need to use something like this:
sound: Sound = pg.mixer.Sound(buffer=b"".join(sound_chunks))

rate, _, _ = pygame.mixer.get_init()
print (f"Rate {rate}")

data = pygame.sndarray.samples(sound)
print (data.shape)
meter = pyln.Meter(rate) 
loudness = meter.integrated_loudness(data)
print(loudness)    


Works perfectly, thank you very much! Glad that the sound object could be used as is.

And NB pygame allows to save data as file. Ref here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292444/pygame-mixer-save-audio-to-disk
